# How to convert clang source file to llvm IR?

Tags: llvm, clang++

When I try to convert some clang cpp source code to IR, the header in the file just lost:

```
clang -emit-llvm -c tools/DDGrammarPluginTooling/DDGrammarPluginTooling.cpp 
tools/DDGrammarPluginTooling/DDGrammarPluginTooling.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'clang/AST/AST.h' file not found
#include "clang/AST/AST.h"
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 1 error generated
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a header, but you haven't told `clang` where to look for those headers. Locate the `AST.h` that you're trying to use, and add an `-I` option to the compiler's arguments, with the path to the folder where the subfolder `clang` resides.

It's not a given that clang's development headers are installed - normally clang/llvm packages only have the binaries. So on Linux you'd want to install the development packages that contain the headers you need. You can use `find /usr -iname AST.h` to see if maybe the header is already installed.

Comment: I had appended the para "-I/Volumes/build/llvm-project/clang/"  to the command . Same error appears . I just replace it with "-I/Volumes/build/llvm-project/clang/include" .

Comment: "-I/Volumes/build/llvm-project/clang/include" works well .

Answer (score 0):

"clang++ -S -emit-llvm -std=c++14 /Volumes/build/llvm-project/clang/tools/DDGrammarPluginTooling/DDGrammarPluginTooling.cpp  -I/Volumes/build/llvm-project/clang/include -I/Volumes/build/llvm-project/build/tools/clang/include -I/Volumes/build/llvm-project/llvm/include -I/Volumes/build/llvm-project/build/include/" works !!! I got the IR file .